# Sharepoint: Is there a way to replace the popup with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there anyway to replace the javascript popup window for DispFrom, EditFrom or NewForm with jQuery popup plugin like popup.js?

I managed to get all forms work with :

```
/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=' + ListGUDI + '&ID=' + ItemID +
```

`PageType=4` # can be repleaced depending of if it's Display,Edit or New - Forms.

Sharepoint provide a view with out the masterpage by adding  `&IsDlg=1` to the end of the link which is great.

Does anyone have an idea? 
I'm using Sharepoint 2010 and SPServices.

Comment: You can also set master page for system defined page in master page setting. Or use scripts or css in content editor to that page to make that form more attractive.
With jquery custom page i think you have to create custom page with custom code.

Comment: Actually I managed to getting it to work by using the Bootstrap Model Popup, which was great, but I have a problem with Save and cancel buttons. Therefore, I went back and used the default SharePoint popup dialog for now until I find a better solution. But thanks anyway @Jude.